# How to test ViewChildren changes in Angular 2

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have a grid populated with people, each person has a set of actions the user can carry out on them, e.g. Update Email. Those actions are stored in a DevExtreme Select Box. I need to write a simple test which tests if any of the dropdown boxes values have changed.

I am storing the drop down boxes in @ViewChildren like so:

```
 @ViewChildren(DxSelectBoxComponent) actionSelectBoxes: QueryList<DxSelectBoxComponent>;
```

Using a function which either proceeds with client creation or resets all of the select box instances like so:

```
public inviteClicked(id: number) {
this.confirmationDialog.show(this.newExamMessage, 'Create a client',
  () => this.createAClient(id),
  () => this.actionSelectBoxes.forEach((x) => x.instance.reset())
);
}
```

Could anyone provide any sort of tips on how I can write a unit test for it, don't necessarily need code but maybe steps and what I could try? I cannot use spies for this task.

Currently my test looks like this, it is lucking any type of logic, any help appreciated:

```
it('should reset selection if cancelled', fakeAsync(() => {
  setupComponent();
  mockConfirmationDialogService.extend({
    show: (_, __, onSuccess: Function, onCancel: Function) => onCancel()
  })
  component.inviteClicked(1);
  flush();
  expect(1).not.toBe(2);
}));
```